# copy parent-child data to another table with different parent-child ids

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a assets table which has assetid (GUID) column and parentassetId (GUID) column.
Need to copy the records to the same table with new GUIDs for assetids.
How to do that? cursor or temp tables? Any ideas appreciated/

Thanks
Venky

Comment: Another table or same table?  Title says one and body another.

Answer (score 0):

Either a cursor or a temp table should work--if it's a one-time copy and performance is not a concern, I would just choose whatever you are more comfortable with.

If you have other ways of uniquely identifying the rows, you may have other options as well.